# Runtime join in lightswitch

Tags: linq, join, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a generic *group members* table with a GUID for a "group type" and a GUID for "referenced object". An example would be if I have a table of customers(each having a GUID) I can group them under "already paid" by creating a group GUID and in my "Group members table" referencing every customer by their respective GUID. This allows for any type of group to be added to the model as we expand(without adding extra tables).

Here is the problem. I have created a subquery in an entity in order to filter the universal *group members* table for a certain group and what "items" are and are not in that group; like so:

```
  partial void ElementsNotMemberOfGroup_PreprocessQuery(int? UniversalGroupTypeIDParameter, int? UniversalGroupsIDParameter, ref IQueryable<UniversalGroupMember> query)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.UniversalGroup.UniversalGroupType.UniversalGroupTypeID == UniversalGroupTypeIDParameter);
        query = query.Where(x => x.UniversalGroup.UniversalGroupsID != UniversalGroupsIDParameter);
    }
```

This returns the GUIDs for the referenced object in the group, but for a user that's useless. I need to join this table and my customers table at runtime on the GUID so I can extract the customer info and display it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

LightSwitch wasn't really created with this kind of scenario in mind. LightSwitch makes things very easy for you when you create relationships between tables that are, well, "related". When you do this, you never need *manual joins* between entities.

While it's *possible* to do something *similar* to what you're describing (see the link below), it's a lot more work to achieve it, and in my opinion it isn't really worth the extra trouble. Not only that, but as you're discovering, it complicates even the most simple operations.

In essence, you're working **against** LightSwitch, instead of **with** it. My advice to you would be that if you really must do this type of *manual optimization*, then LightSwitch may not be the best product for you to use.

Beth Massi has a blog article, [Using Different Edit Screens Based on Record Types (Table Inheritance)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/01/20/using-different-edit-screens-based-on-record-types-table-inheritance.aspx), which isn't exactly what you're doing, but it may give you some ideas if you decide to still use LightSwitch for your project.